# Javafx choicebox/dropdown looses focus on keyboard down arrow and moves to next item

Tags: list, drop-down-menu, focus, javafx, items

In a JavaFX application, I have two textboxes and three choicebox on a screen. 
They are all placed in vertical manner.

On navigating by keyboard TAB when focus reaches fist choicebox,if i click on keyboard Down arrow, then instead of opening the items for that choicebox, focus moves to next choicebox and displays items from it.

I tried to manually override this by creating a keypress event method on first choicebox, still the focus, moves to next choicebox.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put event filter in the parent component that contains those controls.

```
/**
* prevent move focus on pressing UP/DOWN
*/
pnlRadioButton.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
            event.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Added the addEventFilter to Scene. Working perfectly now. Thanks.